# IF statement with Vlookup based on condition

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I am currently refining my Google sheet for orders our company receives, but would like some help in creating a condition to an VLOOKUP formula.

To keep the sheet clean, text only appears on input of L column.
We have a second sheet with a simple costing.

This is the formula;

```
=IF(CONCATENATE(L371)="","",VLOOKUP(L371,COSTING!F:G,2,false))
```

However, this works for only one supplier at the moment.
Is there a way of adding a condition to take into account a second cell on the main sheet?

Example;
Adding this into the VLOOKUP ...

```
If X371 = 'SUPPLIER NAME1' look here (L371,COSTING!F:G,2,false), If X371 = 'SUPPLIER NAME2' look here (L371,COSTING!M:N,2,false)
```

Still learning formulas, so haven't quite mastered how to combine statements.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Not clear. Better put some sample data and expected output. You can share a dummy google-sheet here.

Comment: From your current explanation it seems you can use `IFERROR()` function.

Comment: You can do a bunch of IF checks, and use VLOOKUP and explicitly define the ranges BUT if you're planning on having more than just a few it will start getting hard to maintain.  With INDEX+MATCH you could do it completely dynamically and expand it at will.

Comment: As @Harun24HR says, it would be helpfull if you share some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Apologies for the clarity. Basically, sheet1 has the sale data (we need to populate costs). Col A=supplier, Col B=Product, Col C=size and Col D=Costing. All blank until we enter a product SKU in column B. Size (C) fetches data depending on SKU entered. Once the sizing cell has activated, the VLOOKUP formula above for Column D to lookup a cost for column D. If Column A had variable data, this then becomes more complex. I have accepted an answer for now, since we currently only have 2 suppliers. But as Chris mentioned, this may get trickier with changes. I can re-look at this down the track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(L371="","",if(X371="SUPPLIER NAME1",vlookup(L371,COSTING!F:G,2,false),If(X371="SUPPLIER NAME2",VLOOKUP(L371,COSTING!F:G,2,false))))
```